# Multiple CSS media Query not showing any result

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, media-queries, edx

Below is the script within my head tag. The `min-width:500` is working properly but the immediate next query `max-width:499px` doesn't seem to work, I tried it with and without `screen and` and even adding it in styles.css stylesheet didn't work. I'm trying it just on my screen, and it is supposed to work. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            h2 {
                color: orangered;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
                body{
                    color:greenyellow;
                    background-color: black;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
                body {
                    color:pink;
                    background-color: navy;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles.css">
```

Can anyone tell why is my VSCode not able to predict `mid-width` or `max-width` but accepts it while writing.

Answer (score 0):

I Checked your code in VS Code, it is working fine for Background color but it is not changing color of text(H2 tag), i don't think there is any problem with VS Code you can do this to change text color.

When you are writing media query you are changing background color and text in body, but if you are using h2 tag then it is not working so you should write specific code for h2

Try below code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        h2 {
            color: orangered;
            text-align: center;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
            h2 {
                color: green;
            }
            body {
                background-color: black;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
            h2 {
                color: pink;
            }
            body {
                background-color: navy;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h2>TechWithVP</h2>
    Some other text
</body>

</html>
```